# If we use or two times and and one time in same condition then which one it should take? I have mention the code for the same

Tags: python

This is a simple code just want to clear one thing in this :

```
x=3
if x<5 or x>2 and x==5:
  print("ok")
else:
   print("no output")
```

Output

```
Output : no output
```

My question is why it gave this output even though the third condition is not true.

Comment: The answer is what you just said: The third condition isn't true. Therefore it goes to the else statement and prints `no output`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple "or" , "and" logics

```
OR...

True or True = True         
True or False= True         
False or True= True         
False or False= False
   
And...

True and True =True
True and False=False
False and True=False
False and False=False

similarly,

at x=3
x<5 is True , x>2 is also True --> so we get True or True i:e; True
but x==5 is false --> so we get True and False i:e; False
so the outcome will be True and False i:e; False so the output will be "no output"
```